# Javadoc Constant Field Values for Strings

Tags: java, javadoc

I don't like the way the Javadoc "Contant Field Values" page lists String constants.

Example:

```
public static final String REGEXP_PATTERN = "^\\s*$";
```

On the Javadoc page this constant will be listed with a value of `^\\s*$` which I think is just plain wrong, it should have been `^\s*$`.

The fact that javac requires `\` to be escaped is irrelevant. The *value* of the field - if you ask me - is `^\s*$`, and this is what Javadoc should list.

Is there are way I can achieve this?

The issue at hand is that - believe or not - our Javadoc documentation is also being used by non-Java people. And for non-Java people is just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why should non-java people read javadoc? It exist to help **java** programmers... And talking about **java**, `"^\s*$"` is wrong, because if you copy/paste this into code it won't compile

Comment: "*The value of the field - if you ask me - is "^\s*$"*". But if you ask Java, it's "^\\s*$".

Comment: Consider other escapes (e.g. tab; return,) control characters, etc. that can be represented in string literals. You may find that meaning is lost if you change the way this works. It will also defy the expectations of any Java developer that looks at it.

Comment: Guys:  Counter argument:  If a have an int constant which happens to be expressed in the source code as "4*100" would you then really say that the Constant Field Values should display "4*100" or would you say Javadoc should display "400" ?  (it does, correctly,  the latter). Bottom line: the way a constant happens to be expressed in source code (because of peculiarities of that language's source code format) is irrelevant to the actual **value**. What Javadoc displays for this String example is not the **value**, just like 4*100 isn't the value in my int example.

Comment: In the example you give, the _value_ of the field is `^\s*$` (without quotes), not `"^\s*$"`.  What the JavaDoc "constant field values" page gives you is not the field value exactly, but rather the Java language expression that you would need to use to replace the field name if you wanted to "inline" it.  For example, for fields of type `long` the value is given with a trailing `L` and `float` with a trailing `f`.

Comment: @IanRoberts. Agreed on the quotes thing. Have edited the question for clarity.

Comment: How about `<P>Regex For zero or more whitespace characters, constrained to a line--<I>value</I> is {@code ^\s*$}</P>`? Seems like a whole lot less effort compared to overridding the standard doclet.

Comment: @aliteralmind. Understood. But I was hoping for a solution where I wouldn't have to maintain/document the same defaults twice.

Comment: This is what I do (but I display the literal Java code-value, not the "value" as you describe). The documentation is *right next* to the actual value, practically, so I don't find it a burden.

Comment: The documentation is not meant to be copied and pasted, anyway. That's not an excuse. They're CONSTANT FIELDS; you'd use the field directly. "case 'NUMBER' then 'BIGDECIMAL'" becomes "case \'NUMBER\' then \'BIGDECIMAL\'", because this part of javadoc is simply broken. It obviously parses the string at first, then adds bogus escapes to it later. OP is right to be annoyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there are way I can achieve this?

You would need to create your own doclet by subclassing the default one, a brief look through the [relevant source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/com/sun/tools/doclets/formats/html/HtmlDoclet.java) suggests that you would just need to provide your own subclass of `ConstantsSummaryWriterImpl` whose [`getValue(FieldDoc)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/com/sun/tools/doclets/formats/html/ConstantsSummaryWriterImpl.java#ConstantsSummaryWriterImpl.getValue%28com.sun.javadoc.FieldDoc%29) method is overridden to use `member.constantValue()` in place of `member.constantValueExpression()`.

To wire this writer in at the appropriate place you would then also need to subclass `HtmlDoclet` and override `configuration()` to return your own subclass of `ConfigurationImpl` which in turn returns your own subclass of `WriterFactoryImpl` which in turn returns your custom constants writer, and finally use the `-doclet` option to `javadoc` to tell it to use your custom doclet instead of the standard one.

Comment: Thanks. This is the way to go. I wish there was a simple switch for this but as an alternative perhaps we'll need to the rethink the whole idea of using that particular Javadoc page for other than strictly Java people. Dunno. But thanks.

Comment: @nolan6000 if this is just for one or two specific classes it may indeed be simpler to write a little Java program that goes through these classes with the reflection API to extract the relevant details and build a `.csv` (or whatever) that your non-Java people can open in Excel.

Comment: Yep, agreed. As you may perhaps have guessed we use that particular Javadoc page to explain to users of our software what some default configuration values are.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String REGEXP_PATTERN = "^\\s*$";
```

"\" is just an escape character for "\" - without it the code won't compile.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But the question is not about what `\\` is for in a Java string literal.

Comment: "case 'NUMBER' then 'BIGDECIMAL'" becomes "case \'NUMBER\' then \'BIGDECIMAL\'" - not only is the escaping not needed for documentation, but it also gets spuriously added where it doesn't belong.